# printf "Modification of a read-only value attempted" error

Tags: perl, printf

when attempting to print object as in:

```
print "$response{_content} \n";
printf OUTPUT "$response{_content} \n";
```

The printf statement generates error "Modification of a read-only value attempted"

It's an intermittent error.  Only happens once in a while, but this program needs to be 100% reliable.  dang.

It prints fine to STDOUT.

What am I doing wrong?  arrgh!

Comment: Why do you change from `print` to `printf` when you print to a filehandle? (Also, why are you still using global `FILEHANDLE`s instead of lexically scoped variables?)

Comment: What Chris said :D 
From the docs: "__The first argument of the list will be interpreted as the printf format [..] Don't fall into the trap of using a printf when a simple print would do. The print is more efficient and less error prone__"

Comment: cool.  thanks.  i thought i had to use printf to print to a FILEHANDLE.  thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first argument of `printf` is interpreted as output format, not output itself. See [perldoc -f printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) and [man 3 printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for details.

The problem is, `printf` might occasionally try to write to its args *(this has even been the source of several vulnerabilities in [C programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string))*, for instance:

```
perl -we 'printf "abc%n\n", $_; print "$_\n";'
```

As you can see, this sets `$_` to 3, which is the number of characters written before `%n` occurred. Try %n without further args and you'll see the exact error message from OP.

Long story short: use `print` unless you really need advanced formatting. Keep first argument to `printf` r/o unless you really need even more advanced formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to inspect stdout for the failures. My guess is that once in a while, $response{_content} contains sequences that have special meaning to printf.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error message, also with printf, but I was doing this:

```
printf "%-10s $value\n", $label;
```

The value sometimes contained hex-encoded data from weblogs. Besides doing the padding with the "x" operator, I found that getting the value out of the format string also worked:

```
printf "%-10s %s\n", $label, $value;
```

I thought problem in the format string might be due to percents (%) being interpreted as a formatted value, but fiddling with the ampersands (&) made the error go away. Regardless, inserting a value where it will be interpreted now seems like something to avoid.